# How to calculate scrollWidth of HTML page for fixed height without using UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

We can use the following to calculate the scrollWidth of an HTML page in a UIWebView with a fixed height.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"]
```

Is it possible to do this evaluation on local HTML pages without loading a request into a UIWebView?

Would like this to occur on a separate thread.

Comment: Why are you wanting to get the scrollWidth of local HTML pages?

Comment: Its unlikely that you would be able to accurately calculate this without rendering it. Since you need to render your HTML you would need to use UIWebView or another similar framework.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want this run on a separate thread?

Comment: @JoeCortopassi I do not want to block the UI while I calculate size for local HTML pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**(sort of). The html would need to be rendered in some capacity to be able to get any kind of measurements. **The reason for this is inherent in the way html/css/javascript work together** (javascript modifies html/css properties, css modifies html). If you **had to** get the width without using a UIWebView, you would be stuck with one of two options:

1. **Render the page yourself**, whether it's with your custom code (thousands of man hours, don't do this) or some open source library. I doubt this will be any faster than UIWebView, and will likely introduce unexpected bugs.
2. **Measure the page in the background, and store that value somewhere**. This would basically be a form of caching for the size. If the pages are static from when you ship, just do it manually, and hard code it. If they are dynamic, write a class to measure them on startup and store the value. The **dynamic measurement would require UIWebView**

**EDIT:**

Are you trying to do this because UIWebView is blocking you're main thread, causing jerkiness in your app? If so, have you considered trying something like this?:

```
 UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
 webview.delegate = self;
 [webview loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlFromString:@"/path/to/file.html"]]];
```

... and then later on...

```
 - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
 {
    // run your code to get scroll width of page
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly how the current implementation works. It blocks the UI and main thread when parsing 80 local HTML files, from an ePub file.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy Have you gone into Instruments to make sure UIWebView is blocking the main thread, instead of the system getting bogged down by the shear volume of files to access and parse? Also, accessing a file will block the thread it's on as well. Have you considered pre-loading these files into NSData or something, then use that to load the web view. Are these 80 files static? Cause if they are, your best bet is still to hard code the values